# Interpreting classification metrics for multiclass imbalance

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, model-evaluation, roc, multi-class

I am at the point of reporting my results in a research article conducted. The dataset is highly imbalanced with `class 1` and `class 4` the minority classes. I am kind of loss how bet to interpret my result in the results discussion section. I computed these metrics as in the table below:

[image]

Often I see people compute roc_auc per class, but I would like to know if computing `roc_auc_score` as a weighted average (as in my case here suffice to give good interpretation of model performance, i.e. using:

```
skelearn.meretics.roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted',
                               multi_class='ovr', labels=[0,1,2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 1):

Average (weighted) ROC-AUC based on all possible class comparisons is appropriate to report.